# AngularJS - How to get the actual previous path

Tags: angularjs

In `angularjs` I have configured the `$routeProvider` something like below.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
.
.
.
$routeProvider.when('/user/:id/edit', {templateUrl:'/path/to/template', controller:'SomeCtrl'});
.
.
.
});
```

In my controller `SomeCtrl` how can i get the `Actual Previous Path`.

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $route){
  //Let say,
  //previous route is : #/user/1/edit
  //and current route is #/user/2/edit

  //I am trying to make backRoute
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(e, $currentRoute, $previousRoute){
    // '$previousRoute.originalPath' gives me : /user/:id/edit
    // '$previousRoute.params' gives me : {id:"1"}

    //how can i merge these two so I can make Actual Previous Path
    //backRoute = makeActualRoute($previousRoute.originalPath, $previousRoute.params) 

  })

});
```

I have logged `console.log($previousRoute)` to inspect the object in console but did not found the actual previous route there.

I have read this [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) , but cannot find the hint.

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve this kind of information you should use the [`$location` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) and its events.

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(e, currentLocation, previousLocation){
    // Do whatever you need to do.
})
```

Here's a fiddle showing an example: http://jsfiddle.net/k578N/